# Datastore Queries in JDO with an array field

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

In my appengine Application I use a datastore; one of the field (category) of the datastore is an array of integer. I want find all the elements of my datastore where the array field category contains a particular int x. How can I write the query? I try the following but doesn't work:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery("select from "+Channel.class.getName()+" where category.contains("+x+")");
```

Comment: JDOQL syntax is java syntax. There is no such "array.contains" in Java, and nothing equivalent in JDOQL

Comment: Thank you for your response, So I can't select only the elements of my datastore where the array field category contains a particular int x, is it right?

Comment: Can you remap your Java object model as a Collection instead of array?  Your query would then likely work.

Comment: Thank you! I follow your advice!